# How to make WPF app work as a child process in Citrix

Tags: wpf, winforms, citrix, xenapp

I am working on a 3rd party application that allows plugins to be written in .NET 1.1. I have decided I would like to write my plugin to call a seperate process from the .NET 1.1 plugin (achieved using Process.Start). This is fine- I create a new process that is a WPF app.

When I launch this through MSTSC everything works as expected, however when I run the app through Citrix XenApp, the WPF child app fails to render correctly, and the mouse position starts going crazy- the child process window is basically not usable. Is there a way to avoid this happening?

If I create a seperate WPF application and deploy this through Citrix everything works fine. If I create a child Windows forms app in .NET 3.5, that also works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you need to apply the hot fix described in [Microsoft KB 955692](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955692). Once that is applied this issue no longer occurs.